# Find nearby places android java

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have a list of latitude and longitude stored in database. Now I'm trying to develop a function on finding nearby place from my current location. Means that, i have to search all the latitude and longitude from my database and see which of the places are within my area will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
Location.distanceBetween(lat1,lon1,  lat2,lon2, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the distance from one two-dimensional point to another you can use the Haversine formula, (without calling any API functions.)

```
// All measurements are in meters
var rad = function(x) {
  return x * Math.PI / 180;
};

var getDistance = function(coord1, coord2) {
  // This is the Earth's radius
  var earthRad = 6378137; 
  var dLat = rad(coord2.lat() - coord1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(coord2.lng() - coord1.lng());
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(rad(coord1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(coord2.lat())) *
    Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
  var b = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var distance = earthRad * b;

  // Returns distance from coord1 to coord2 in meters
  return distance;
};
```

Your question is a bit broad so this might not be the best solution. If you were constantly updating your current location you'd have to implement a Tree Sorting algorithm or some other way of optimizing performance rather than checking through your database for distances on every update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object. The distanceBetween or distanceTo method will give you the 'as the crow flies' distance between two points. From there you can filter your results and display only the places you want to.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i use

```
  public void nearBy() { 
        if (map.getMyLocation() != null) {//check if my location was found
            db = new MyDatabase(MainActivity.context);
            Cursor medecin = db.lireMedecin();//read values from database
            map.clear();//clearing the map
            while (medecin.getPosition() < medecin.getCount()) { //cheking if this doctor is nearby...
                String Lat1 = medecin.getString(5);//doctor's latitude
                String Lon1 = medecin.getString(6);//doctor's longitude
                LatLng me = new LatLng(map.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), map.getMyLocation().getLongitude());//my location
                LatLng med = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Lat1), Double.parseDouble(Lon1));//doctor location
                if (CalDist(me, med) < 6) {//if distance is < 6km add marker to the map
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(med).title(medecin.getString(1) + " " + medecin.getString(2))
                            .snippet(medecin.getString(4)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(Icone(medecin.getString(7).charAt(0))))); //showing the doctor on the map 
                }
                medecin.moveToNext();//next doctor
            }
        } else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Gps signal not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//can't find my position
    }
```

calculate distance :

```
 public static double CalDist(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius = 6371;//­radius of earth in Km 
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude ;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude ;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude ;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude ;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                   Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                   Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return Radius * c;
    }
```